# Simplest example of using Google C++ Testing Framework with CMake

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cmake, googletest

I have a very simple C++ library (one header file, one .cpp file). I want to write unit tests for this project using the Google C++ Testing Framework.

Here is the directory structure:

```
~/project1
 |
 |-- project1.cpp
 |-- project1.h
 |-- project1_unittests.cpp
 \-- CMakeLists.txt
```

I do not plan to write my own main() function. I want to link with gtest_main as mentioned in the [primer](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/primer.md#writing-the-main-function). What should CMakeLists.txt contain?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Enable CMake's built-in testing subsystem:

```
# For make-based builds, defines make target named test.
# For Visual Studio builds, defines Visual Studio project named RUN_TESTS.
enable_testing()
```

Compile an executable that will run your unit tests and link it with gtest and gtest_main:

```
add_executable(runUnitTests
    project1_unittests.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(runUnitTests gtest gtest_main)
```

Add a test which runs this executable:

```
add_test(
    NAME runUnitTests
    COMMAND runUnitTests
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped a lot. I had to link with both gtest, gtest_main and pthread. I also had to specify absolute paths for libgtest.a and libgtest_main.a; is there a better way to add these static libraries to the linker search path?

Comment: Got it! I set and exported GTEST_ROOT in bash and then include_directories($ENV{GTEST_ROOT}/include) with
link_directories($ENV{GTEST_ROOT}).

Comment: In my case, I chose to add the subdirectory gtest-1.6.0, since this wasn't working for me (no -lgtest found). I used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8507723/how-to-start-working-with-gtest-and-cmake and got things working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplest one,

1.Create a simple source file,

```
$ cat simplegtest.cpp 

#include<gtest/gtest.h>
TEST(Mytest, failing_test){
    EXPECT_TRUE(false);
}
```

2.Compile it using below command,

```
$ LDLIBS="-lgtest_main -lgtest" make simplegtest
g++     simplegtest.cpp  -lgtest_main -lgtest -o simplegtest
```

3.Execute the test executable using below command,

```
$ ./simplegtest 
Running main() from /home/prashant/work/thirdparty/googletest-release-1.8.1/googletest/src/gtest_main.cc
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from Mytest
[ RUN      ] Mytest.failing_test
simplegtest.cpp:4: Failure
Value of: false
  Actual: false
Expected: true
[  FAILED  ] Mytest.failing_test (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from Mytest (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test case ran. (1 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 0 tests.
[  FAILED  ] 1 test, listed below:
[  FAILED  ] Mytest.failing_test

 1 FAILED TEST
```