# How to start working with GTest and CMake

Tags: unit-testing, cmake, googletest

I have recently been sold on using CMake for compiling my C++ projects, and would now like to start writing some unit tests for my code. I have decided to use the Google Test utility to help with this, but require some help in getting started.

All day I have been reading various guides and examples include the [Primer](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/primer.md), an [introduction at IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-googletestingframework.html?ca=drs-) and some questions on SO ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4222169/769220) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5901489/769220)) as well as other sources I've lost track of. I realise there's plenty out there but somehow I am still having difficulties.

I'm currently trying to implement the most basic test, to confirm I've compiled/installed gtest right and it's not working. The only source file (testgtest.cpp) is taken almost exactly from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4222169/769220) previous answer:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "gtest/gtest.h"

TEST(sample_test_case, sample_test)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(1, 1);
}
```

and my associated CMakeLists.txt is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(basic_test)

# Setup testing
enable_testing()
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIR})

# Add test cpp file
add_executable(runUnitTests
    testgtest.cpp
)

# Link test executable against gtest & gtest_main
target_link_libraries(runUnitTests ${GTEST_LIBRARY_DEBUG} ${GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARY_DEBUG})

add_test(
    NAME runUnitTests
    COMMAND runUnitTests
)
```

Note that I have chosen to link against gtest_main instead of providing the main at the end of the cpp file as I believe this will allow me to scale testing up more easily to multiple files.

When building the generated .sln file (in Visual C++ 2010 Express) I unfortunately get a long list of errors of the form

```
2>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: virtual __thiscall std::basic_iostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::~basic_iostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >(void)" (??1?$basic_iostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@UAE@XZ) already defined in gtestd.lib(gtest-all.obj)
```

which I think means that I'm not successfully linking to the gtest libraries. I have made sure that when linking against the debug libraries, I have then tried to build in debug mode.

**EDIT**

Having done some more digging, I think my issue is something to do with the type of library I am building gtest into. When building gtest with CMake, if `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` is un-checked, and I link my program against these .lib files I get the errors mentioned above. However, if `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` is checked then I produce a set of .lib and .dll files. When now linking against these .lib files the program compiles, but when run complains that it can't find gtest.dll.

What are the differences between a `SHARED` and a not `SHARED` library, and if I choose not shared, why doesn't it work? Is there an option in the CMakeLists.txt for my project that I am missing?

Comment: You can avoid including GTest sources in your own by using `ExternalProject_Add` rather than `add_subdirectory`.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9695234/424459) for details.

Comment: Why do we have access to ${gtest_SOURCE_DIR} in the solution example above? How/where is that variable declared?

Comment: Oh it's declared in gtest-1.6.0/CMakeLists.txt: "project(gtest CXX C)" which makes the variables gtest_SOURCE_DIR and gtest_BINARY_DIR available.

Comment: What does `enable_testing()` do?

Comment: instead of answering in the edit, put the solution into an answer, and accept it

Comment: @updogliu: It enables ctest and the 'test' (or 'RUN_TESTS') target. It plays together with the add_test() cmake command.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

The solution involved putting the gtest source directory as a subdirectory of your project. I've included the working CMakeLists.txt below if it is helpful to anyone.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(basic_test)

################################
# GTest
################################
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY (gtest-1.6.0)
enable_testing()
include_directories(${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include ${gtest_SOURCE_DIR})

################################
# Unit Tests
################################
# Add test cpp file
add_executable( runUnitTests testgtest.cpp )
# Link test executable against gtest & gtest_main
target_link_libraries(runUnitTests gtest gtest_main)
add_test( runUnitTests runUnitTests )
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the add_test() does, but it doesn't seem to result in the test binary running... Am I missing something?

Comment: Not to beat a dead horse but I thought this was worth mentioning again.  Fraser's comment above makes a very important point:  "You can avoid including GTest sources in your own by using ExternalProject_Add rather than add_subdirectory."  See Fraser's answer and comments for details here:


 http://stackoverflow.com/a/9695234/1735836

Comment: In my case, I also needed to add `pthread` to the linked libraries, changing the second last line to `target_link_libraries(runUnitTests gtest gtest_main pthread)`

Comment: @weberc2 You have to run `make test` to run the tests, or run `ctest` from the build directory.  Run `ctest -V` to see the google test output as well as the `ctest` output.

Comment: Doesn't work: https://i.imgur.com/ADGD0cs.png . I don't have a gtest-1.6.0 directory. What does it even do? I downloaded `googletest` from github and I have a `googletest` directory. Inside that `googletest` directory I have another `googletest` directory, which one am I supposed to set there? Also, I have the outer `googletest` directory in the `dependencies` directory, not in the root directory of the CMake project. So what do I put in the ADD_SUBDIRECTORY function to actually make it work?

Comment: I don't have the `${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}` variable set either. Same problem again: which one of the directories I have to set: outer or inner one?

Comment: Try to use CMake FetchContent for this (no need for including gtest manually like that anymore): https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/googletest/README.md#incorporating-into-an-existing-cmake-project

Comment: This is a great question/answer. Can you add something to show what your folder hierarchy looked like, to put the solution in context?

Answer (score 51):

Here is a complete working example that I just tested. It downloads directly from the web, either a fixed tarball, or the latest subversion directory.

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.1)

project (registerer)

##################################
# Download and install GoogleTest

include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(gtest
  URL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/release-1.8.0.zip
  # Comment above line, and uncomment line below to use subversion.
  # SVN_REPOSITORY http://googletest.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ 
  # Uncomment line below to freeze a revision (here the one for 1.7.0)
  # SVN_REVISION -r700
  
  PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/gtest
  INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)
ExternalProject_Get_Property(gtest source_dir binary_dir)

################
# Define a test
add_executable(registerer_test registerer_test.cc)

######################################
# Configure the test to use GoogleTest
#
# If used often, could be made a macro.

add_dependencies(registerer_test gtest)
include_directories(${source_dir}/include)
target_link_libraries(registerer_test ${binary_dir}/libgtest.a)
target_link_libraries(registerer_test ${binary_dir}/libgtest_main.a)

##################################
# Just make the test runnable with
#   $ make test
    
enable_testing()
add_test(NAME    registerer_test 
         COMMAND registerer_test)
```

Comment: I don't know why you got downvoted for this. Your solution prevents someone from having to check in Google Test onto version control. Kudos for your solution.

Comment: The URL you use is now broken. An up-to-date URL is `https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/release-1.8.0.zip`

Comment: greate answer! also we can use ```GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/google/googletest.git GIT_TAG release-1.8.1``` instead of URL

Comment: The URL to the gtest latest release is: `https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/release-1.10.0.zip`

Comment: Why don't you use `find_package(GTest REQUIRED)`?

Comment: Won't this download and build GTest with every build? Most users don't want to rebuild GTest every time they run `make`

Answer (score 19):

You can get the best of both worlds. It is possible to use `ExternalProject` to download the gtest source and then use `add_subdirectory()` to add it to your build. This has the following advantages:

- gtest is built as part of your main build, so it uses the same compiler flags, etc. and hence avoids problems like the ones described in the question.
- There's no need to add the gtest sources to your own source tree.

Used in the normal way, ExternalProject won't do the download and unpacking at configure time (i.e. when CMake is run), but you can get it to do so with just a little bit of work. I've written a blog post on how to do this which also includes a generalised implementation which works for any external project which uses CMake as its build system, not just gtest. You can find them here:

- https://crascit.com/2015/07/25/cmake-gtest/
- https://github.com/Crascit/DownloadProject

**Update:** This approach is now also [part of the googletest documentation](https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/master/googletest#incorporating-into-an-existing-cmake-project).

Comment: IMO, this is perhaps the cleanest way to implement Google test with a CMake project. I wish the moderators would pay more attention to content and quality of the answers.

Comment: The linked DownloadProject.cmake generalised module is great. It feels like the basis for cmake having a package management system where all I need are a list of links to CMake compatible github urls.

Answer (score 14):

Most likely, the difference in compiler options between your test binary and the Google Test library is to blame on such errors. That's why it's recommended to bring in Google Test in the source form and build it along with your tests. It's very easy to do in CMake. You just invoke  `ADD_SUBDIRECTORY` with the path to the gtest root and then you can use public library targets (`gtest` and `gtest_main`) defined there. There is more background information in this [CMake thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/googletestframework/zHy-rrKz_Ho/xJNkzm14UskJ) in the googletestframework group.

[edit]
The `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` option is only effective on Windows for now. It specifies the type of libraries that you want CMake to build. If you set it to `ON`, CMake will build them as DLLs as opposed to static libs. In that case you have to build your tests with -DGTEST_LINKED_AS_SHARED_LIBRARY=1 and copy the DLL files produced by the CMake to the directory with your test binary (CMake places them in a separate output directory by default). Unless gtest in static lib doesn't work for you, it's easier not to set that option.

Comment: Great thanks, didn't realise you could build completely seperate projects within the same CMakeLists like that. I can now safely say that EXPECT_EQ(1.0 == 1.0) passes and EXPECT_EQ(0.0 == 1.0) fails. Now time for more real tests...

Answer (score 4):

The OP is using Windows, and a much easier way to use GTest today is with **vcpkg**+cmake.

---

Install vcpkg as per https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg , and make sure you can run `vcpkg` from the cmd line. Take note of the vcpkg installation folder, eg. `C:\bin\programs\vcpkg`.

Install gtest using `vcpkg install gtest`: this will download, compile, and install GTest.

Use a CmakeLists.txt as below: note we can use *targets* instead of including folders.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(sample CXX)
enable_testing()
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
add_executable(test1 test.cpp source.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test1 GTest::GTest GTest::Main)
add_test(test-1 test1)
```

Run cmake with: (edit the vcpkg folder if necessary, and make sure the path to the vcpkg.cmake toolchain file is correct)

`cmake -B build -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\bin\programs\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake`

and build using `cmake --build build` as usual.
Note that, vcpkg will also copy the required gtest(d).dll/gtest(d)_main.dll from the install folder to the Debug/Release folders.

Test with `cd build & ctest`.

Answer (score 3):

Just as an update to @Patricia's comment in the accepted answer and @Fraser's comment for the original question, if you have access to CMake 3.11+ you can make use of CMake's [FetchContent](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/module/FetchContent.html) function.

CMake's FetchContent page uses googletest as an example!

I've provided a small modification of the accepted answer:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
project(basic_test)

set(GTEST_VERSION 1.6.0 CACHE STRING "Google test version")

################################
# GTest
################################
FetchContent_Declare(googletest
GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/google/googletest.git
GIT_TAG release-${GTEST_VERSION})

FetchContent_GetProperties(googletest)
if(NOT googletest_POPULATED)
  FetchContent_Populate(googletest)
  add_subdirectory(${googletest_SOURCE_DIR} ${googletest_BINARY_DIR})
endif()

enable_testing()

################################
# Unit Tests
################################
# Add test cpp file
add_executable(runUnitTests testgtest.cpp)

# Include directories
target_include_directories(runUnitTests 
                      $<TARGET_PROPERTY:gtest,INTERFACE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>
                      $<TARGET_PROPERTY:gtest_main,INTERFACE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>)

# Link test executable against gtest & gtest_main
target_link_libraries(runUnitTests gtest
                                   gtest_main)

add_test(runUnitTests runUnitTests)
```

You can use the `INTERFACE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` target property of the gtest and gtest_main targets as they are set in the google test [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/CMakeLists.txt) script.

Comment: In CMake >= v3.14 you can forego the explicit `target_include_directories` and use `FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)` instead. This will both populate the content and add it to the main build. [CMake FetchContent - more info](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/module/FetchContent.html)

Comment: FetchContent is a CMake module. So it is not available in CMake by default, and you need to include it using `include(FetchContent)` before using it.

Answer (score 2):

> Having done some more digging, I think my issue is something to do with the type of library I am building gtest into. When building gtest with CMake, if BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is un-checked, and I link my program against these .lib files I get the errors mentioned above. However, if BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is checked then I produce a set of .lib and .dll files. When now linking against these .lib files the program compiles, but when run complains that it can't find gtest.dll.

That is because you have to add -DGTEST_LINKED_AS_SHARED_LIBRARY=1 to compiler definitions in your project if you want to use gtest as a shared library.

You could also use the static libraries, provided you compiled it with gtest_force_shared_crt option on to eliminate errors you have seen.

I like the library but adding it to the project is a real pain. And you have no chance to do it right unless  you dig (and hack) into the gtest cmake files. Shame. In particular I do not like the idea of adding gtest as a source. :)

Answer (score 1):

I decided to throw something generic together real quick demonstrating a different way of doing it than the answers previously posted, in hope that it might help someone. The following worked for me on my mac. Firstly I ran setup commands for gtests. I just used a script I found to setup everything.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# install gtests script on mac
# https://gist.github.com/butuzov/e7df782c31171f9563057871d0ae444a

#usage
# chmod +x ./gtest_installer.sh
# sudo ./gtest_installer.sh

# Current directory
__THIS_DIR=$(pwd)


# Downloads the 1.8.0 to disc
function dl {
    printf "\n  Downloading Google Test Archive\n\n"
    curl -LO https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/release-1.8.0.tar.gz
    tar xf release-1.8.0.tar.gz
}

# Unpack and Build
function build {
    printf "\n  Building GTest and Gmock\n\n"
    cd googletest-release-1.8.0
    mkdir build 
    cd $_
    cmake -Dgtest_build_samples=OFF -Dgtest_build_tests=OFF ../
    make
}

# Install header files and library
function install {
    printf "\n  Installing GTest and Gmock\n\n"

    USR_LOCAL_INC="/usr/local/include"
    GTEST_DIR="/usr/local/Cellar/gtest/"
    GMOCK_DIR="/usr/local/Cellar/gmock/"

    mkdir $GTEST_DIR

    cp googlemock/gtest/*.a $GTEST_DIR
    cp -r ../googletest/include/gtest/  $GTEST_DIR
    ln -snf $GTEST_DIR $USR_LOCAL_INC/gtest
    ln -snf $USR_LOCAL_INC/gtest/libgtest.a /usr/local/lib/libgtest.a
    ln -snf $USR_LOCAL_INC/gtest/libgtest_main.a /usr/local/lib/libgtest_main.a

    mkdir $GMOCK_DIR
    cp googlemock/*.a   $GMOCK_DIR
    cp -r ../googlemock/include/gmock/  $GMOCK_DIR
    ln -snf $GMOCK_DIR $USR_LOCAL_INC/gmock
    ln -snf $USR_LOCAL_INC/gmock/libgmock.a /usr/local/lib/libgmock.a
    ln -snf $USR_LOCAL_INC/gmock/libgmock_main.a /usr/local/lib/libgmock_main.a
}

# Final Clean up.
function cleanup {
    printf "\n  Running Cleanup\n\n"

    cd $__THIS_DIR
    rm -rf $(pwd)/googletest-release-1.8.0
    unlink $(pwd)/release-1.8.0.tar.gz
}

dl && build && install && cleanup
```

Next, I made a simple folder structure and wrote some quick classes

```
utils/
  cStringUtils.cpp
  cStringUtils.h
  CMakeLists.txt
utils/tests/
    gtestsMain.cpp
    cStringUtilsTest.cpp
    CMakeLists.txt
```

I made a top level CMakeLists.txt for the utils folder, and a CMakeLists.txt for the tests folder

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

project(${GTEST_PROJECT} C CXX)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 98)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 98)

#include .h and .cpp files in util folder
include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")

##########
# GTests
#########
add_subdirectory(tests)
```

This is the CMakeLists.txt in the tests folder

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

set(GTEST_PROJECT gtestProject)

enable_testing()

message("Gtest Cmake")

find_package(GTest REQUIRED)

# The utils, test, and gtests directories
include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
include_directories("/usr/local/Cellar/gtest/include")
include_directories("/usr/local/Cellar/gtest/lib")

set(SOURCES
  gtestsMain.cpp
  ../cStringUtils.cpp
  cStringUtilsTest.cpp
)

set(HEADERS
  ../cStringUtils.h
)

add_executable(${GTEST_PROJECT} ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(${GTEST_PROJECT} PUBLIC
  gtest
  gtest_main
)

add_test(${GTEST_PROJECT} ${GTEST_PROJECT})
```

Then all that's left is to write a sample gtest and gtest main

**sample gtest**

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "cStringUtils.h"

namespace utils
{

class cStringUtilsTest : public ::testing::Test {

 public:

  cStringUtilsTest() : m_function_param(10) {}
  ~cStringUtilsTest(){}

 protected:
  virtual void SetUp() 
  {
    // declare pointer 
    pFooObject = new StringUtilsC();    
  }

  virtual void TearDown() 
  {
    // Code here will be called immediately after each test
    // (right before the destructor).
    if (pFooObject != NULL)
    {
      delete pFooObject;
      pFooObject = NULL;
    }
  }


  StringUtilsC fooObject;              // declare object
  StringUtilsC *pFooObject;
  int m_function_param;                // this value is used to test constructor
};

TEST_F(cStringUtilsTest, testConstructors){
    EXPECT_TRUE(1);

  StringUtilsC fooObject2 = fooObject; // use copy constructor


  fooObject.fooFunction(m_function_param);
  pFooObject->fooFunction(m_function_param);
  fooObject2.fooFunction(m_function_param);
}

} // utils end
```

**sample gtest main**

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "cStringUtils.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv); 
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

I can then compile and run gtests with the following commands from the utils folder

```
cmake .
make 
./tests/gtestProject
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the other answers are good but are completely ignoring the existence of the [`GoogleTest`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GoogleTest.html) CMake module.

A minimal demo using CMake's `GoogleTest` would be:

```
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
    googletest
    GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/google/googletest.git"
    GIT_TAG "main"
)
# For Windows: Prevent overriding the parent project's compiler/linker settings
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)

include(GoogleTest)

add_executable(example example.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example GTest::gtest_main)
gtest_discover_tests(example)
```

An explanation as to why [`gtest_discover_tests`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GoogleTest.html#command:gtest_discover_tests) or [`gtest_add_tests`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GoogleTest.html#command:gtest_add_tests) should be preferred in most cases over the explicit `add_test()` is given bellow:

> Both commands are intended to replace use of add_test() to register tests, and will create a separate CTest test for each Google Test test case. Note that this is in some cases less efficient, as common set-up and tear-down logic cannot be shared by multiple test cases executing in the same instance. However, it provides more fine-grained pass/fail information to CTest, which is usually considered as more beneficial. By default, the CTest test name is the same as the Google Test name (i.e. suite.testcase); see also TEST_PREFIX and TEST_SUFFIX.

Answer (score 0):

Yours and VladLosevs' solutions are probably better than mine. If you want a brute-force solution, however, try this:

```
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS /NODEFAULTLIB:\"msvcprtd.lib;MSVCRTD.lib\")

FOREACH(flag_var
    CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE
    CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO)
    if(${flag_var} MATCHES "/MD")
        string(REGEX REPLACE "/MD" "/MT" ${flag_var} "${${flag_var}}")
    endif(${flag_var} MATCHES "/MD")
ENDFOREACH(flag_var)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest CMakeLists.txt I distilled from answers in this thread and some trial and error is:

```
project(test CXX C)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6.2)

#include folder contains current project's header filed
include_directories("include")

#test folder contains test files
set (PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR test) 
add_executable(hex2base64 ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/hex2base64.cpp)

# Link test executable against gtest nothing else required
target_link_libraries(hex2base64 gtest pthread)
```

Gtest should already be installed on your system.

Comment: It's really not a good practice to add library like this in CMake. One of the main objective of cmake is to never have to make assumption like "This libs should already be installed...". CMake check that library is here, and if not, an error is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer, using official googletest docs

```
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
  googletest
  # Specify the commit you depend on and update it regularly.
  URL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/5376968f6948923e2411081fd9372e71a59d8e77.zip
)
# For Windows: Prevent overriding the parent project's compiler/linker settings
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)

# Now simply link against gtest or gtest_main as needed. Eg
add_executable(example example.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example gtest_main)
add_test(NAME example_test COMMAND example)
```