# undefined reference to testing::internal::EqFailure in gtest

Tags: c++, opencv, googletest

I am trying to do a test for a function using GoogleTest an now it is not finding anymore the `EqFailure` *thing*:

```
/usr/include/gtest/gtest.h:1337: undefined reference to `testing::internal::EqFailure(char const*, char const*, testing::internal::String const&, testing::internal::String const&, bool)'
```

I am writing the test like this:

**test_file.cpp**:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

#include "tools/CMorphology.hpp"

TEST(erode_Morph, crossKernel_Morph)
{
  // initialize matrix to be eroded
  cv::Mat matrix = (cv::Mat_<uchar>(5, 5) << 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                                             1, 1, 0, 1, 1,
                                             1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                                             1, 0, 1, 1, 1,
                                             1, 1, 1, 1, 1
            );
  // initialize the cross kernel
  cv::Mat kernel = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_CROSS, cv::Size(3, 3));
  // initialize the vector expected as output
  cv::Mat verMat = (cv::Mat_<uchar>(5, 5) << 1, 1, 0, 1, 1,
                                             1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
                                             1, 0, 0, 1, 1,
                                             0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
                                             1, 0, 1, 1, 1);

  // call erode(...)
  Morphology morphology;
  cv::Mat matrixOut;
  morphology.erode(matrix, kernel, matrixOut);

  for (int i = 0; i < matrixOut.rows; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrixOut.rows; j++)
    {
      EXPECT_EQ(matrixOut.ptr<uchar>(i)[j], verMat.ptr<uchar>(i)[j]);
    }
  }
}
```

I am using OpenCV and if needed, I'll post the other files.

`CMake` file is here:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(EXECUTABLE_NAME lpdetect)
project(${EXECUTABLE_NAME})

option(DEBUG "Display images for each step" OFF)

if (DEBUG)
        set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-reorder -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-switch -std=gnu++11 -DDISPLAY_IMGS -DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK")
else()
        set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-reorder -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-switch -std=gnu++11 -DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK")
endif()

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED core
                             imgproc
                             features2d
                             nonfree
                             highgui
                             )

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem
                                       program_options
                                       system
                                       thread
                                       locale
                                       regex
                                       date_time
                                       log
                                       log_setup
                                       timer
                                       )

include_directories(src/main/cpp
                    ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
                    ${OpenCV2_INCLUDE_DIRS}
                    )

add_executable( ${EXECUTABLE_NAME}
                             src/main/cpp/main.cpp
# and the other files
                             )

target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS}
                                         "-laws-cpp"
                                         "-lcasablanca"
                                         ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
                                         "-lcrypto"
                                         )


find_package(GTest REQUIRED gtest_main
                            pthread)

enable_testing()

include_directories( ${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

add_executable(${EXECUTABLE_NAME}_test src/test/cpp/test_Morphology.cpp
                                       src/main/cpp/tools/CMorphology.cpp
                                       src/main/cpp/tools/CMorphology.hpp
                       )

target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME}_test
                                       ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES}
                                       ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
                                       ${GTEST_LIBRARIES}
                                       )

add_test(${EXECUTABLE_NAME}_test
         ${EXECUTABLE_NAME}_test
         )
```

I have done this a wile ago, and after some commits it is displaying this error. Why does it no longer find that?

Comment: Can you try running your build verbosely, and seeing if there is a `-L` link directory option to the directory containing your gtest libraries?  Are you linking statically or dynamically?  The error occur at link time (not runtime), correct?

Comment: It happens at link time, yes. I linked it dynamically

Comment: Should it be `Gtest_LIBRARIES` instead of `GTEST_LIBRARIES`?  I'm not too familiar with cmake, but the basic idea is that cmake should generate a `-lgtest` on the command line, and possible a `-L/path/to/gtest`. Can you see if that is part of your link command line?  Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8507723/how-to-start-working-with-gtest-and-cmake

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've had exactly this error message in the following scenario:

Using a messy Ubuntu 14.10 (which has a mismatch between `libgtest-dev` (GTest 1.6), and `google-mock` (GMock 1.7 with bundled GTest 1.7), I chose the wrong path - installed GMock 1.6, to match the system's `libgtest-dev`).

For some time the project compiled, but then - after a git pull, some new features of 1.7 were used and I needed to upgrade to 1.7. I installed it from google-mock package (rebuilt with CMake, then copied to `/usr/include` and `/usr/lib`). Then, I launched the build, and the gtest.h:1337 (isn't this line number telling?) linker error started happening.

After hours of inspecting the libs with `nm -C libgtest.a` (repeat for `libgtest_main.a`, `libgmock.a` and `libgmock_main.a`), I found that the `testing::internal::EqFailure` function takes 2x `std::string`, and not `testing::internal::String`.!!

I checked the headers - nothing there - `std::string` everywhere. Where was the strange reference?

Well - it was in the old object files, build with GTest 1.6 headers! So now:

**TL;DR**

- Remove and rebuild all old objects which you built with GTest 1.6 headers. (`make clean`, or something to that effect, YMMV)
- Upgrade GMock, if you haven't.
- Use only bundled GTest (from GMock), if you haven't.

Comment: Have this worked for you? Actually I have passed to boost test, I use boost, no? :)

Answer (score 11):

Here I provide another case that may possible be a reason for such a link error:

In my project, for some compatibility reason I have to compile my project with a macro "-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0", which forces the compiler to use old C++11 ABI for compilation(in GCC>5.0). However, the gtest library used was compiled before, and was just compiled directly without this option.

And finally i got a similar error but the function signature of testing::internal::EqFailure is like "testing::internal::EqFailure(char const*, char const*, std::__cxx11::string const&, std::__cxx11::string const&, bool)". I don't quite remember the exact signature but there was something like "__cxx11" in the string args rather than std::string. And when I found it I figured out that this may caused by that macro I used.

So this problem was finally solved by recompiling the gtest with  "-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0" and then link the new library.

Hope this answer may help for someone.

Answer (score 7):

Probably this is less likely to be the problem compared with the accepted solution, but in my case I was getting the same error as the OP due to using g++-5 to compile gtest vs. g++-4.8 on the project which I was trying to compile, which resulted in [symbols not being found](http://developers.redhat.com/blog/2015/02/05/gcc5-and-the-c11-abi/).

If the accepted answer doesn't work for you then you should probably double check that you have used the same compiler for your project as gtest.

Comment: Also check you're using the same standard library as gtest (e.g. libstdc++ rather than libc++ depending on how you built gtest).

Comment: That was it in my case. Used gcc 4.9 to build gtest and used gcc-8 to build my project.
I went back to build gtest using "CC=gcc-8 CXX=/usr/bin/g++-8 cmake ../ && make && sudo make install" and it worked.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem as @yizhi-wang. It's also very similar to @tomasz-gandor's and @tim-rae's issues: the string type differs across different `gtest` builds and this is often caused by a `std::string` ABI break which occured between GCC 4 and 5.

In my case, when issuing the `conan install` command, I noticed the following warning text:

```
************************* WARNING: GCC OLD ABI COMPATIBILITY ***********************

Conan detected a GCC version > 5 but has adjusted the 'compiler.libcxx' setting to
'libstdc++' for backwards compatibility.
Your compiler is likely using the new CXX11 ABI by default (libstdc++11).

If you want Conan to use the new ABI, edit the default profile at:

    /home/john/.conan/profiles/default

adjusting 'compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11'

************************************************************************************
```

I followed the advice and the linker error went away.

Comment: Also using Conan - updating the profile with `conan profile update settings.compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11 default` did the trick.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was also my case and it fixed for me!

Answer (score 3):

My case was similar to the first answer, I intended to build google test from sources and link it to the application. But I had the gtest-dev package installed in the system, and forgot to set the include paths correctly. 
After removing the gtest-dev package and setting the include path the problem is gone. The answer from Tomasz helped a lot to narrow the issue.

Comment: Worked for me too, just removed gtest-dev from the system.

Comment: Same here, updating gmock and removing libgtest-dev helped.

Answer (score 1):

My case: undefined declaration to ASSERT_STREQ(...)

Solution: rebuild gtest with `BUILD_GMOCK == OFF`

It works for me, worth a try ~