# What is the best way to integrate GTest with existing project?

Tags: cmake, googletest

I am trying to integrate GTest to my existing project. Below is my following project structure:

```
--trunk(folder)
  --sources(folder)
    --Prj1
    --Prj2
    --CMakeLists.txt
  --test(folder)
    --test1(folder)
      --test1.h
      --test1.cpp
      --main.cpp
      --CMakeLists.txt(1)
    --test2(folder)
      --test2.h
      --test2.cpp
      --main.cpp
      --CMakeLists.txt(2)
  --CMakeLists.txt(3)
--CMakeLists.txt
```

Now i want to integerate the GTest for this project. I would have probably 10 tests to be carried out. i would like to know the best way to write /integrate my project.

**CMakeList.txt(1)**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
add_test(dummy dummy)
add_executable(dummy main.cpp test1.cpp test1.h)
target_link_libraries(dummy gtest gtest_main)
```

**CMakeList.txt(3)**

```
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY ("C:/gtest/1.7.0"${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/gtest")
include_directories(${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include ${gtest_SOURCE_DIR})  
add_subdirectory(test)
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include<gtest/gtest.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

With this i am able to create gtest and gtest_main librabry, but would like to create only one time and link them with all the tests. And moreover i would like to have the test in a folder view in my visual studio project. Could anyone help me to achieve this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start working with GTest and CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8507723/how-to-start-working-with-gtest-and-cmake)

Comment: @usr1234567: With add_subdirectory() i am getting two projects gtest and gtest_main. Is there a possible that i use my own main and use gtest libraries as dependencies but not as a project?