# How to create a CMakeLists.txt for GoogleTest?

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest

I'm new to cmake and I'm trying to create a CMakeLists.txt for compiling my test files.
I have 3 files: `calc.cpp`, `calc.hpp`, and `calc_test.cpp` and I use the following command to compile my tests:

```sh
g++ -o calc_test calc_test.cpp calc.cpp -lgtest -lpthread
```

which generates a binary file (`calc_test`) that I execute to run my tests.

Here's my `calc.hpp`:

```cpp
#ifndef CALC_HPP_
#define CALC_HPP_

int add(int op1, int op2);
int sub(int op1, int op2);

#endif
```

My `calc.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "calc.hpp"

int add(int op1, int op2) {
    return op1 + op2;
}

int sub(int op1, int op2) {
    return op1 - op2;
}
```

And my `calc_test.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include "calc.hpp"

TEST(CalcTest, Add) {
    ASSERT_EQ(2, add(1, 1));
    ASSERT_EQ(5, add(3, 2));
    ASSERT_EQ(10, add(7, 3));
}

TEST(CalcTest, Sub) {
    ASSERT_EQ(3, sub(5, 2));
    ASSERT_EQ(-10, sub(5, 15));
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Now I have created a CMakeLists.txt file to compile my test files and it generates Makefile successfully, but when I execute `cmake --build .` it throws `undefined reference` error.
Here's the content of my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(Google_Test)

add_library(TestModlue calc.cpp)
target_link_libraries(TestModlue -lgtest -lpthread)

add_executable(calc_test calc_test.cpp)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You probably need to link your `calc_test` application against googleTest, instead of your library.

Comment: How can I do that? As I've said I'm new to cmake. @AlexeyLarionov

Comment: Best approach is to create a library from your main project. This library can you then link against the main executable or the Google Test binary, as both are individual executables, but need to share your main code. I had a sample project, but I can't find it. :(

Comment: Thanks, I'll share my files. @Devolus

Comment: List the library names without `-l`, i.e. `target_link_libraries(TestModlue gtest pthread)` Furthermore you're linking `gtest` to your lib, but link neither that lib nor gtest to the executable. Since `calc_test.cpp` us he file using gtest, you should link the lib to the target that actually makes use of `gtest`, not some other target. `target_link_libraries(calc_test gtest TestModlue pthread)` seems to be the correct version of the `target_link_libraries` command. (To be positioned after `add_executable`)

Comment: If you just want to **replicate** the command line `g++ -o calc_test calc_test.cpp calc.cpp -lgtest -lpthread`, then it creates a single executable without the library. That is, your `CMakeLists.txt` with `add_library` doesn't correspond to the your intentions. But creating a library and test executable is actually a proper way for use gtest. See the [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8507723/how-to-start-working-with-gtest-and-cmake) and its answers. E.g. your current approach corresponds to that answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34980359/3440745.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as an example how to setup a project structure. It basically follows what I wrote above in my comment. [CMake Google Test Example](https://github.com/kaizouman/gtest-cmake-example)

```
* Your main code is put inside a library instead of directly including it in the application
* Create a seperate main binary (your application)
* Create another binary which contains your google tests
* Link both projects (application/gtests) against your library
```