# Adding GoogleTest to existing project give linker errors

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest

I have a project that uses CMake to get built. I wanted to test my program using GoogleTest.
So I followed the instructions of the ReadMe file of GoogleTest, and added the marked lines to my `CMakeLists.txt` (My OS is Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS) :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(replicatorProject)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

### I added the the following lines which I got from the ReadMe of GoogleTest 

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
        googletest
        # Specify the commit you depend on and update it regularly.
        URL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/609281088cfefc76f9d0ce82e1ff6c30cc3591e5.zip
)

# Now simply link against gtest or gtest_main as needed. Eg
add_executable(example test/CrushMapperTest.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example gtest_main)
add_test(NAME example_test COMMAND example)

### until here (above)

find_library(CRUSH_LIBRARY libcrush.so /usr/local/lib/crush/ REQUIRED)
find_package(CppKafka REQUIRED)
add_executable(replicator src/main.cpp src/kafka/KafkaConsumer.cpp src/kafka/KafkaConsumer.h src/crush/CrushMapper.cpp src/crush/CrushMapper.h src/Replicator.cpp src/Replicator.h src/crush/Bucket.cpp src/crush/Bucket.h src/crush/Device.cpp src/crush/Device.h)
target_link_libraries(replicator LINK_PUBLIC ${CRUSH_LIBRARY} CppKafka::cppkafka)
target_include_directories(replicator PRIVATE /usr/local/include)
```

My Project structure looks like this:

[image: Project Structure]

`CrushMapperTest.cpp` looks like the following:

```cpp
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}

TEST(case1, name){
    EXPECT_EQ(1,1);
}
```

However, if I run the test, I get a lot of undefined reference errors from my linker (here are some of them):

```
/usr/bin/ld: /home/lorik/Uni/Praktikum/Projekt/replicator/test/CrushMapperTest.cpp:13: undefined reference to `testing::internal::AssertHelper::~AssertHelper()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/lorik/Uni/Praktikum/Projekt/replicator/test/CrushMapperTest.cpp:13: undefined reference to `testing::internal::AssertHelper::~AssertHelper()'
```

Now I am new to using CMake and I don't get what else I need to add to make the linker find the Google Test functions. I was looking through some other SO posts with similar problems ( like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8507723/how-to-start-working-with-gtest-and-cmake?rq=1)) a while ago , but so far no suggested solution helped while trying to dowload google test directly through CMake.

What am I doing wrong? Do I need another CMakeLists.txt for the test directory?

**Solution**

I had to add `FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)` after the `FetchContent_Declare(...)` line

Comment: I'm not sure if `gtest` and `gtest_main` libraries are interchangeable as the comment suggests.

Comment: I think you need to add 'enable_testing()' in your CMakeLists.txt

Comment: I tried linking against gtest aswell. I still get undefined reference errors but for other functions. @Yksisarvinen

Comment: Where do I have to put it in? I tried above the `add_executable(example ...)` line and I also tried after `add_test(...)` line, but still get the same error @Lieuwe

Comment: you need to link to gtest library

Comment: As mentioned in the comment above, linking against gtest unfortunately did not solve the problem @AnisBelaid

Comment: The call to `FetchContent_Declare` only **declares** how to populate the project. I see no  call to `FetchContent_MakeAvailable` or similar which actually **populates** the project. In the current form you seems to link with system-installed googletest, which could be built for different compiler options.